# existence of fractal

Tags: fractals, geometry, dimension-theory

I have a question about fractals;

Suppose $\alpha\in[0,1]$ is real number, is there any fractal $F_\alpha$, such that $Dimension(F_\alpha)=\alpha$?
If yes, do we have any method to construct such fractal?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  But this is not the place to ask.  See the FAQ for suggestions of other places to ask.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the Wikipedia page about Hausdorff dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are many examples, and constructible ones abound. I'll just mention one example: There is a theorem of Jarnik from the 1920's or 30's that says that for any $\tau\ge 2$ the collection of real numbers $x$ for which the inequality
$$|x-a/q|\le 1/q^{\tau}$$ has infinitely many solutions $a,q\in\mathbb{N}$, has Hausdorff dimension $2/\tau$.

Comment: Many Thanks Dear AH, your answer is sufficient. 